# Do any commercially available generic circuits use only discrete components?

Tags: pcb, integrated-circuit, components, manufacturing

I'm currently toying with embarking upon a totally crazy hobby project, which would prohibit the use of *any* component that cannot be 100% verified manually: obviously this completely rules out all forms of integrated circuit—even discrete components would have to be manually tested and verified.

On the other hand, it does not rule out the use of *pre-made* circuits: provided that they can be verified (e.g. following the circuit tracks and testing individual components).  It would be a significant timesaver if such pre-made circuits existed for generic tasks typical of basic ICs.

I appreciate that there's pretty much no demand for such circuits (except perhaps at a basic educational level), so imagine that they are not commercially viable.  Certainly my searches so far have not uncovered anything.

**But do they exist?**  Does *anyone* sell generic logic circuits from discrete components?

Comment: Why do you need to be able to test each component individually? Also it may be hard to test a circuit that's pre-built because it will be connected to all sorts of other components so the other components will interact with your discrete component under test. You'll have to unsolder it and resolder it if you were interested in testing it individually. Along the way, you'd have the chance of damaging the component. All in all, why wouldn't you want to build it from scratch?

Comment: @horta: It's a security-driven project and paranoia dictates one cannot trust the ICs not to have been maliciously subverted (they might, for example, contain some sort of state machine that only yields incorrect outputs after a particular sequence of inputs that wouldn't be detected during testing).

Comment: Ok, so you can at least use integrated logic gates, right?

Comment: @horta: That's a fair point re the difficulties in testing a pre-made circuit and one that may ultimately push me down the road of building my own.  I had however previously dismissed that concern on the basis that one ought to be able to rely on discrete components not to contain sophisticated state machines... but if one is to be *truly* paranoid... ;)

Comment: @horta: Can I?  Who is to say that they're reliable?

Comment: You can open random samples of simple chips and simply inspect them optically. That ought to allow use of SSI and MSI logic chips and any linear ICs, as well as discretes.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany: Is optical inspection of simple chips something that a hobbyist can do without any special equipment?  I've never opened a chip before...

Comment: @eggyal integrated logic gates can be tested for all input and output conditions pretty easily.

Comment: @horta: But one cannot know that the IC doesn't contain a state machine that will yield different outputs if presented with a particular *sequence* of inputs.

Comment: @eggyal You can have them opened for a reasonable cost (tens of dollars) and then you're just into a $500 Chinese microscope.

Comment: If a digital IC manufacturer put in a state machine into discrete logic gates, nobody would be able to use the components because they wouldn't work exactly as expected which is absolutely necessary when creating something as complicated as a small microprocessor out of these things. People do it and are successful, which implies that there's no secret state machine in them.

Comment: @horta: Oh, I don't doubt that the ICs other people have are perfectly reliable.  I just want to have 100% certainty that the ICs that *I* have are.  Can you guarantee that, for (extreme) example, the NSA haven't switched them in the post before I received them?

Comment: Is it aerospace or nuclear project ? DO-254 ?

Comment: @zeqL: No, it isn't.  Does that make a difference?

Comment: You say this is a hobbyist project, so what exactly is it you hope to learn from this exercise, and how large a system do you anticipate building using this technique? Obviously, you could have some "standard" modules of your own design made by the hundreds, and then build your system from those modules. Many early computer systems were built this way, such as the DEC PDP-8 minicomputer. With modern SMT packaging, the modules could be much smaller, but the concept remains the same.

Comment: @DaveTweed: Yes, and having my own modules manufactured in this manner is my fallback plan.  The intention is pretty much exactly as you describe: build a minicomputer with 100% certainty that the operation has not been covertly impaired by any malicious adversary.

Comment: If you are concerned about state machines hidden inside let's say a 74HC00, why stop there? There might be a state machine inside that transistor you want to use, or what about that 1k resistor?

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen: Yes, there might.  But the more basic the component, the more sophisticated that the state machine would have to be to achieve anything useful.  A single transistor (or resistor) would somehow have to coordinate with thousands of others to achieve anything useful (okay, something similar could be said of logic gates, but the chance such a degree of sophistication could *fit* in the casing of a discrete component is orders of magnitude less than in the casing of an IC).

Comment: @eggyal : aerospace and nuclear project have a high reliability in mind and we don't use only discrete NPN or PNP transistor to achieve the reliability.   Also, you may be able to check each transistor individually, but would you be able to do the same for each function ? Or does the complexity will made this impossible ?

Comment: @eggyal: so what level of components are you willing to trust? resistors and transistors? Analog chips (555!), SSI TTL, MSI, LSI, CPLD, FPGA, Micocontrollers? Idem for your tools: are you going to read all lines of let's say the GCC source?

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen: What point is there in reading GCC source if one cannot trust the compiler? :P  It's a hobby project.  I'm not intending to produce anything *useful*.  I merely hope, one day, to have the the personal satisfaction of having built something in which I can trust.  And you're right, deciding upon a level of component to trust is a little arbitrary: perhaps I should [fabricate my own semiconductors](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/64758), huh?  (No, that wasn't serious.)  So yes, I choose to trust transistors and resistors.

Comment: All of this discussion in the comments seems merely to be me defending/justifying my question.  I don't think it has added much to the actual question I have asked (i.e. "does anyone produce such discrete-component circuits?"), to which it seems the answer is an emphatic "no".  If someone wants to post that as an answer, I'd be happy to accept.

Comment: We're just trying to help keep you on-topic for this site. If this is just a straight shopping question, it's off-topic and will have to be closed. Besides, the meta-question is much more interesting!

Comment: @DaveTweed: Thanks - definitely not trying to be off-topic.  It wasn't really *intended* to be a "straight shopping question", but I suppose that's what it amounts to.  What is the "meta-question"?

Comment: The meta-question is the one I asked in my first comment: What are you really trying to achieve here? We're trying to clarify that and help you reach that goal.

Comment: @eggyal considering you downvoted a good answer bcause you "want to buy them pre-made", you don't deserve any help. Besies what you want is a novelty product that noone makes.

Comment: @Passerby: Had I asked "*how can I build logic gates from discrete components?*" then that post would have deserved my upvote (and probably my acceptance). But that wasn't my question. Indeed, as it stood, the post was not useful to me as it completely failed to address my question and provided no information that I did not already have. So I downvoted it (which, to my understanding, is the correct response on SE for posts that are not useful). If that means that I suddenly "don't deserve any help" then, frankly, this is not a community of which I wish to be part.

Comment: @eggyal - (1) See my answer in tcrosley's comments (2) Cornelius put effort into trying to help. You are correct that he did not in fact address the core question BUT in a community of ordinary everyday people it's better just to appreciate his desire to help and not vote either way than to risk the ire of some by doing so AND commenting. If you wish to be part of a community containing only people who behave rationally and nicely your choices will be "very limited" [tm].

Comment: @RussellMcMahon: You may well be right that verifying a PDP-8 or similar (if I can get my hands on one, together with sufficient documentation) may be a better solution for me than building a CPU from scratch!  As to your second point, I obviously need to spend more time familiarising myself with this community - as it appears the etiquette differs markedly from that of StackOverflow (with which I am much more familiar): there votes (up or down) are in no way personal, but are merely a ready means of providing feedback; I added an explanatory comment, as I've always thought it more polite.

Comment: @eggyal An excellent solution along the lines of what Cornelius suggested and NOT matching your request would be to make small cards with a semi-standardised pinout with each card implementing a logic function as per Cornelius's suggestion. These can use modern chip resistors and eg SOT23 transistors. While SMD components are challenging to solder at first, with very little experience they become exceedingly easy to handle. Next stage from there is a solder bath or toaster oven reflow solderer. Speed of construction can be high and better than using ICs per se  as ICs still need a ...

Comment: ... pcb or similar. Standardised cards could be joined using wire-wrap - still a very useful and flexible technology. The advatnage of this approach is that it uses off the shelf transistors and chip components (R C D) and you can get these from a vast number of suppliers or buy surplus reels randomly or ... . If you cannot get parts this way that are unable to be untampered with to your satisfaction then there is liable to be no solution that will work for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could buy used Digital Equipment [(DEC) "Flip-Chip" boards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip_Chip_%28trademark%29), that were used in the PDP-8 and other computers 50 years ago.  They are available on eBay typically for $10 apiece.  (Search for "PDP-8 flip".)

There are NAND/NOR gates, inverters, flip-flops, one-shots, decoders -- all built using transistors and diodes.  (I believe some newer ones started to use IC's, so you would want to stay away from those.)

These cards were usually plugged into a backplane, and the pins on the back coming from the connectors were connected using [wire-wrap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wire-wrap).  (The linked article even shows the backplane of a PDP-8I.)

Here's a dual flip-flop:

[image]

Schematics should be readily available after a little searching.

You could also look into buying a used PDP-8 or other DEC computer in non-working order and get a whole lot of these.  Then you would also get the backplane and connectors.

Although wire-wrap isn't used that much anymore, the tools (including wire-wrap guns, much nicer than the little manual wrap tools) are available from Digi-Key and other sources, as well as [30-guage wire-wrap wire](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/R30W-0100/K397-ND/221682).

Comment: This is actually a great suggestion.  I will look into it further.  Thanks!

Comment: I was about to post a short answer exactly along these lines but some people who cannot understand plain English and/or who insist that people are not allowed to ask questions which are perfectly good technically but that they are not comfortable with for irrelevant reasons have put it on hold. ICs on such systems could probably be opened if desired. HOWEVER, doing this makes it very hard to build a useful product. Better would be top buy a working PDP-8 or similar, verify it as desired, then use it for your purpose.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I agree, I don't understand why it was closed, I thought it was very clear what the OP was asking for, even if it was a little unusual.

Answer (score 1):

No :D At least not for your application. Possibly small educational ones though. Educational discrete logic circuits are usually not wired up so that the student can learn it through experience.

Comment: They might suffice, then.  Especially since it permits testing of the individual components without the problems that you identified in your first comment.  But I have not been able to find any such educational circuits...?

Comment: I honestly wouldn't recommend any of the educational kits because they're usually expensive and tailored to doing lots of different things rather than one dedicated thing. They would be extremely expensive for what you want to do since you need tons of components. I'd recommend just buying the discrete components in volume and using lots of large bread boards. In that way, every component will be verifiable by you.